# Generic List C with Multiple Data Fields

Tags: c, generics

I'm trying to create a generic linked list in C that has multiple data fields

```
typedef struct listNode {
void *data1;
void *data2;
void *data3;
struct listNode *next;
} listNode;
```

I need to read from a file in the format

```
name YOB  country 
john 1995 USA
Sam  1990 USA
Tim 1889 AUS
```

So  my plan was to make each node of the list store the info on each line (I've already taken care of finding what kind of variable each column is so I can just type cast the pointer). So for example on line 2

```
typedef struct listNode {
void *data1;   //becomes a string that is john
void *data2;   //becomes a int that is 1995
void *data3;   // becomes a string that is USA
struct listNode *next;
} listNode;
```

My issue is firstly is that even possible or can each element of the list only hold one kind of variable as when I search generic lists, examples only have one void data*

My second issue is that I don't know how many columns the file will have; is there a way to dynamically set the number of data fields?

```
//FILE HAS 5 COLUMNS
typedef struct listNode {
void *data1;
void *data2;
void *data3;
void *data4;
void *data5;
struct listNode *next;
} listNode;

//FILE HAS 2 COLUMNS
typedef struct listNode {
void *data1;
void *data2;
struct listNode *next;
} listNode;
```

Comment: Is the number of colm going to be constant throughout the file?

Comment: @Saurav Sahu Yes it will be

Comment: Answer is NO for dynamic struct formation as its data types must be known at compile time : Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187908/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-define-a-struct-in-c

Comment: @ Saurav Sahu oh ok, if I knew how many columns there are ( lets say 3 like in the first example) the list can contain different types of variables right?

Comment: Normally, you'd use a single `void *data;` in the list, but the list for your triplet would point to a structure with the three fields.  Hence: `struct listNode { void *data; struct listNode *next; };` and `struct person { char name[20]; int yob; char country[20]; };` or thereabouts, and the `void *` values managed would be `struct person *` in disguise.  The same list code can handle single elements, double, triple, quadruple, quintuple, …

Comment: right ok thats a good way of doing it. But what If I dont know the variable type of each column but only how many there were. Thats why my original list node had 3 void* data types so they could be typre casted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't quite get your first issue. Maybe some more explanations?

And for the second one, you will need to dynamically allocate something to store all columns and in the list structure, a pointer to the allocated memory. Below is an example:

```
typedef struct listNode_s {
    void **columns;
    size_t columnsCount;
    struct listNode_s *next;
} listNode;
```

And when creating a list node:

```
void **columns = malloc(sizeof(void*) * count);
for(i=0; i < count; ++i) {
    columns[i] = get_column(i);
}
listNode *node = malloc(sizeof(listNode));
node->columns = columns;
node->columnsCount = count;
//Insert the node to your list

//When freeing your node
free(node->columns);
free(node);
```

P.S. Maybe using a union + enum for type instead of a void* for data is better.

Comment: sorry, so it seems like a basic question but if my list was
typedef struct listNode {
void *data1;   //becomes a string that is john
void *data2;   //becomes a int that is 1995
void *data3;   // becomes a string that is USA
struct listNode *next;
} listNode;

can data1 be a int
data2 be a string
data3 be a char

Or do they all have to be the same type of varible

Comment: @CrispyCashew of course they can be of different types. The member of a struct can be any type, like in my example, listNode has two members and the first is a pointer to void* and the second is a size_t (an unsigned int type mostly used for counting things).

Answer (score -1):

If you want to create one generic list, you could refer to the list definition of Linux kernel.

include/linux/list.h